# Update multiple or single object in an array with specified data from request

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I am not great with MongoDB's advanced techniques.
My record in the MongoDB collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("1"),
    "manager": ObjectId("12345"),
    "code": "PS",
    "title": "Performance System",
    "users": [
        {
            "_user": ObjectId("1"),
            "role": "Member",
        },
        {
            "_user": ObjectId("2"),
            "role": "Member",
        },
        {
            "_user": ObjectId("3"),
            "role": "Member",
        }
    ],
}
```

## Node.js / ExpressJS

I created API to update the array like below but did not work.

```js
const updateProjectMember = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { userID, role } = req.body.userData;

  try {
    const project = await Project.updateMany(
      { _id: req.params.projectID },
      { $set: { "users.$[selectedUser].role": role } },
      { arrayFilters: { "selectedUser._user": { $in: userID } } }
    );
    res.status(200).json(project);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error(error);
  }
```

I use the API parameter to get the project ID. Here is the request body data:

```
{
  userID : ["2","3"];
  role: "Admin"
}
```

So the API will get an array of userID to match and set all "role" fields to "Admin" to all matched.

I wanted the data to be like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("1"),
    "manager": ObjectId("12345"),
    "code": "PS",
    "title": "Performance System",
    "users": [
        {
            "_user": ObjectId("1"),
            "role": "Member",
        },
        {
            "_user": ObjectId("2"),
            "role": "Admin",
        },
        {
            "_user": ObjectId("3"),
            "role": "Admin",
        }
    ],
}
```

Am I doing the right practice? If it is bad practice, what is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Make sure you pass the value with exact type as in MongoDB document. For example: pass string value for _id, same goes to userID array (all the values as string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is fine. Just make sure that you pass the value with the exact type as in the MongoDB document.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const updateProjectMember = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { userID, role } = req.body.userData;
  userID = userID.map(x => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(x));

  try {
    const project = await Project.updateMany(
      { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.projectID) },
      { $set: { "users.$[selectedUser].role": role } },
      { arrayFilters: { "selectedUser._user": { $in: userID } } }
    );
    res.status(200).json(project);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: I did it as string. I forgot to mention that _user is an objectId. If it field not "_id", does mongodb recognize the string as objectId ?

Comment: No, you have to cast the string to ObjectId. Done update my answer.

Comment: I execution the API but it push new object into that array like this `{ "role" : "Admin" }` without ObjectID that use to filter.  It does not update the existing object.

Comment: I solved it. Thank you, the code works fine with your help with the ObjectID. I just fix my side problem that cause API won't work.